# How do I get the object from JAXBElement<Object>

Tags: java, xml

I have :

```
JAXBElement<ArrayOfLeadRecord> r = l.getLeadRecordList() ;
```

How can I get the actual `ArrayOfLeadRecord` as an object? 
It took me so long to unmarshal/convert this `JAXBElement` to the actual object I want.
Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the `getValue()` method.

```
 JAXBElement<ArrayOfLeadRecord> r = l.getLeadRecordList() ;
 List<LeadRecordList> leadRecordList = r.getValue().getLeadRecordList();
```